# Creating a hosted 'web form' for a user to authenticate via SAML

Tags: redirect, saml, onelogin, hosted

We have the following 'use case', and I hope someone can point us in the right direction as to how to develop such functionality:

- User visits a company-hosted site, with an embedded form for SAML SSO - Username, Password, 'Forgot Password' Link.
- User enters details and the login is 'authenticated' (or not)

We have the above working, but upon authentication, the user is taken to the onelogin.com/portal page.  What we want to happen is after a successful authentication, the user is directed to a different page on the company-hosted site.

website.com/login --> SAML Authentication -->website.com/dashboard

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used onelogin but all the SAML IDP configurations that I have used allow you to configure the website ACS (application consumer service).

After successful authentication, the IDP redirects to this URL.